# combine duplicates and keep unique elements using dplyr::distinct

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to combine rows, delete dups, but keep uniques.  I can do the first two, but not the second.  I have a df called subject which looks like this:

```
unique_id   subject     grade
1            Math         88
1            English      78
1            History      98
2            Math         65
2            English      72
2            History      84
```

This code

```
combined <- distinct(subject, unique_id, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

gives me this output:

```
   unique_id    subject     grade
1               Math          88
2               Math          65
```

I'd like to have it look like this:

```
   unique_id    subject                       grade
1               Math, English, History        88, 78, 98
2               Math, English, History        65, 72, 84
```

The solution below works perfectly!  Here is one more wrinkle to the problem.

If I have a data set that looks like this:

```
unique_id   school  subject  grade  sex
    1       great   Math      88    
    1       great   English   78    
    1       great   History   98    male
    2       spring  Math      65    
    2       spring  English   72    female
    2       spring  History   84
```

and run the following code:

```
(r2 <- df %>%
  group_by(unique_id) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(toString(unique(.)))))
```

I get the following output:

```
unique_id   school  subject                     grade       sex
    1       great   Math, English, History      88,78,98     , male 
    2       spring  English, English, History   65,72,84     , female
```

Is there a way to have it combine empty cells with out the commas in sex category, so it can look like this:

```
unique_id   school  subject                     grade       sex
    1       great   Math, English, History      88,78,98     male   
    2       spring  English, English, History   65,72,84     female
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this by pasting (`toString` is a wrapper for `paste(., collapse=", ")`) the unique elements together for each column after grouping by 'unique_id'

```
library(dplyr)
(r1 <- df %>%
        group_by(unique_id) %>% 
        summarise_each(funs(toString(unique(.)))))
#   unique_id                subject      grade
#       <int>                  <chr>      <chr>
#1         1 Math, English, History 88, 78, 98
#2         2 Math, English, History 65, 72, 84
```

Or we can keep it as a `list` and then extract the `list` elements

```
r2 <- df %>% 
       group_by(unique_id) %>% 
       summarise_each(funs(list(unique(.))))
```

From 'r2', we can `unnest` (from `tidyr`) if we needed

```
library(tidyr)
r2 %>%
  unnest()
```

---

If we are using the OP's way with `distinct`, we can remove the `unique` from the `summarise_each`.

```
df %>%
   distinct(subject, unique_id, .keep_all=TRUE) %>%
   group_by(unique_id) %>%
   summarise_each(funs(toString(.)))
```

Comment: thank you, @akrun!  Your first option works perfectly.  One quick question: I tried it with blank cells and noticed I was getting some commas.  Any ideas how to add code to avoid it counting blank cells?  See new example above.  THANK YOU!!!

Comment: @richiepop2  One option would be to either convert it to NA and remove it with `is.na` or otherwise, we can do with `summarise_each(funs(toString(.[nzchar(.)])))`

Comment: I tried the solution you provided but it didn't seem to work.  I'm struggling with how to figure out to combine rows, but skip blanks.  See new code example above.

Comment: @richiepop2  I did tested that and it is working for me using dplyr_0.5.0.  Are you sure that they are blanks i.e. `""` or do you know if they are white spaces `"    "`?